# what ImagePairData layers means in Caffe?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, caffe, caffe2

I have a Caffe .prototxt file and i want to convert Caffe layers in Keras or TensorFlow. There is one layer type: "ImagePairData", i don't understand what this means and what's its conversion to Keras or TensorFlow?
Here is the Layer:

```
layer {
  name: "pairdata"
  type: "ImagePairData"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  image_pair_data_param {
    image_dir: "benchmark_val/train/images"
    label_dir: "benchmark_val/train/gt"
    batch_size: 10
    h_img: 256
    w_img: 256
    h_map: 256
    w_map: 256
    channels: 3
    mean: 0
    scale: 1
    multiclass: false
  }

  include: {phase: TRAIN}
}
```

What layer is similar to this layer in Keras or TensorFlow?

Answer (score 0):

This layer is not part of caffe's "basic" layers (the layers caffe is "shipped" with, see a list of caffe layers [here](http://caffe.help/manual/layers.html)). It is probably a custom layer written by whomever you are trying to take this model from.

Without looking at the code I cannot tell you exactly what this layer does, but my guess is that this layer provides **two** inputs to the net:
1. `"data"` of size 10-3-256-256 (`batch_size: 10`, `channels: 3` and `h_img, w_img: 256`)
2. `"label"` of size 10-1-256-256 (since `multiclass: false` I assume only one "channel" here)

I suppose this layer is an input layer to segmentation/pixel labeling task providing both input (`"data"`) and reference ground truth of the same spatial size (`"label"`).

I think you should write your own input layer in Keras/TensorFlow to have similar functionality.

Comment: Yes @Shai, i'm thinking the same way, but i didn't understand how to combine these two? should i convolute them together or merge them?

Comment: @JITENDERSINGHVIRK this layer does **not** combine the two. I guess the loss layer does that eventually. you'll have to look at the other layers.

Comment: and if you look at Layer both data and label is described as top. so how to combine them?

Comment: @JITENDERSINGHVIRK in caffe a "top" of a layer means output

Comment: oh, Okay. Thanks.